# Почему свойство DataGridCellInfo IsValue всегда false

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Собственно есть DataGrid заполняемый в конструкторе класса. При нажатии на Ячейку `Cell` нужно получить данные этой ячейки в обьект `DataGridCellInfo`.

```
    private DataGridCellInfo _currentCell;
    public DataGridCellInfo CellInfos
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentCell;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentCell = value;
        }
    }
```

XAML датагрида :

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="AppFTPfiles" Margin="0,30,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationCollection}" IsReadOnly="True"
                      CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfos, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                      >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DownloadPDF}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="FTP files" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Собственно коллекция-источник данных :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Documents> ApplicationCollection { get; set; }
    public class Documents
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

И заполнение, что бы не заморачиватся такое :

```
 public documentViewModel()  //Конструктор класса
    {
        ApplicationCollection = new ObservableCollection<Documents>();
        ApplicationCollection.Add(new Documents()
                {
                    Name = "text"
                });
      }
```

По клику по ячейки мне нужно получить текст из текущей ячейки и использовать его далее в комманде. Но свойство келлинфо все время пусто, показывает что структура содержит недопустимые данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обидно что точно такую же операцию делал на другой форме с другой VModel а теперь всю голову сломал и не понимаю в чем ошибка? Подскажите кто с подобным сталкивался?

Comment: мне кажется, что вы что-то не то делаете. Можно узнать зачем вам выносить `DataGridCellInfo` в свойство?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Публичное свойство `DataGridCellInfo` привязано к  `CurrentCell ` датагрида.

Comment: я это понял, мне интересно зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: обычно подобная информация совершенно лишняя в `VM`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Что бы получить значение в этой ячейке

Comment: но ведь значение в ячейке это ваш `Name`, правильно?

Comment: @FoggyFinder верно

Comment: мы можем продолжить обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)? мне кажется так можно быстрее найти решение